# How do I move a Wordpress site on the same server?

Tags: migration

I have a test site on mysite.com/test and I want to move it over (and replace the current Wordpress installation) at mysite.com. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Easiest would be to contact your hosting and tell them to move it, you could also select all files/folders and move (if in cpanel)

Comment: Have you read the support article? https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/#moving-directories-on-your-existing-server